# Best Approach for Auto-Scaling (Avoiding Down Time)

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb, autoscaling, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using AWS for our web application and we are aiming to scale it for millions of users. Right now, we are using AWS Beanstalk "Auto Scaling", where i have defined min, max instances to scale.

Problem:
1- We need to scale it for 1 Million+ Users 
2- Our AutoScaling is working but when we a new instance spins-up (it takes little more time to install the app) and mean while user requests are also starting reaching there (Gets Empty Response, as application is installing).

I want to use the best architecture (Build a Solid Base which we can improve with time) architecure with small amount of time.

P.S: We are using Micro-Services Architecture + API GATEWAY.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of 1 million plus users is vague. Does this mean one million simultaneous users requiring complex database access or simply a million users accessing files on S3 storage? Defining performace requirements is the first step in designing reliable, secure and fault-tolerant systems.

The key to good autoscaling has several factors:

1. Health checks. Your health checks will determine when the load balancer starts sending requests to your backend instances. Your health checks need to be accurate in determining when an instance is available for service and how long to wait before checking for health on new instances (instance startup time).
2. Instance startup and configuration. You need your instances to come online as fast as possible. This usually means creating a preconfigured AMI that does not require downloading and installing updates, packages or applications.
3. Management. Sudden massive increases in traffic is usually predictable. Product announcements, marketing videos, etc. can usually be scheduled and prewarming your platforms can be performed in advance and then shutdown after the event.

A common misperception with autoscaling is that scaling up can be done instantly. This is not the case. To handle massive increases in traffic you either need to pre-warm your environment or have extra redundant capacity to handle instant spikes.

Autoscaling work well with traffic that grows and descreases over time, not all at once. With the exception of serverless platforms, there is no `instant on` for compute services.